# MySQL Multi Table Select SUM Query

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have 3 tables in a database and i need to perform a query that selects all of the rows from one table and joins it with the sum of a column two tables down and then orders on that sum. The tables are for a game. You have a table of teams, a table of users where the user is unique and assigned to a team where users.team_id =  teams.id column and finally a table of items which is the items collected per day by each person. Every day the person enters the number of items collected and this is then summed for their total. The items table is joined by the users.adid = items.user_id.

What i need is a select query that will give me a list of all the teams limited to the teams that have a date within 2015 and then have a column for sum of the items collected by each team which can have multiple team members. This is all then ordered by the number of items from largest to smallest.

Example:

```
| Team ID | Team Name | Total Items |
-------------------------------------
| 1       | Bravo     | 5674        |
| 567     | Charlie   | 16          |
```

Etc.

I have tried using MySQL SUM() but the issue i have been having is the joins, group by's or nested queries that this requires to get the sum of each users items for each team.

Tables Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `teams` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `captain_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `adid` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `first_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `last_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ADID` (`adid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `items` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Tried anything using `SUM()`? http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes i have been experimenting with sum. the issue is that i need to select the sum of something two tables away so i need a join with a group by or a nested query which is posing a problem.

Comment: You could post what you tried and may have failed, that way others could help point out where the errors may have been made.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.id, t.name, t.total
from teams t
inner join users u on t.id = u.team_id
inner join ( select user_id, sum(items) as total
             from items
             where date >= '2015-01-01'
               and date < '2016-01-01'
             group by user_id) t on t.user_id =  u.id
             order by t.total desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, sum(i.items) as totalItems  /* you will get 3 columns as result: "id", "name" and "totalItems" */
FROM teams t /* start selecting from the table "teams"... */
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.team_id = t.id /* ... join the users table ... */
    INNER JOIN items i ON i.user_id = u.adid /* ... and last but not least the items table */
WHERE year(t.date) = 2015 /* filter the teams by year */
GROUP BY t.id /* group the result by team id - you want just one line per team */
ORDER BY totalItems DESC /* order by total items */
```

i saw that in your items-table is also a date - if you want to filter that for the year too, do this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, sum(i.items) as totalItems  /* you will get 3 columns as result: "id", "name" and "totalItems" */
FROM teams t /* start selecting from the table "teams"... */
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.team_id = t.id /* ... join the users table ... */
    INNER JOIN items i ON i.user_id = u.adid AND year(i.date) = 2015 /* ... and last but not least the items table (and filter by year) */
WHERE year(t.date) = 2015 /* filter the teams by year */
GROUP BY t.id /* group the result by team id - you want just one line per team */
ORDER BY totalItems DESC /* order by total items */
```

for joining the items-table with the user-table, you are currently joining an int with a varchar - (items.user_id with users.adid) - why not join the items.user_id with users.id? if that's not possible, i recommend to switch the adid from varchar to int.